# MFC EnableD2DSupport try using StrokeStyle is not working

Tags: c++, mfc, direct2d

I have a MFC application drawing line, texts, rectangles with different colors, etc. without any problem. But I want to draw dot and dashed lines and I didn't find any way to do it ! With my folowing example found into internet, the result is and empty drawing at the end : all the window, not just the guilty DrawLine(), and this without any error or bad status.

Heres some samples of my code :

in constructor :

```
// Enable D2D support for this window:
EnableD2DSupport();

HRESULT hr = D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &m_pD2DFactory);

// Dash array for dashStyle D2D1_DASH_STYLE_CUSTOM
float dashes[] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f};

// Stroke Style with Dash Style -- Custom
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
        hr = m_pD2DFactory->CreateStrokeStyle(
                D2D1::StrokeStyleProperties(
                        D2D1_CAP_STYLE_FLAT,
                        D2D1_CAP_STYLE_FLAT,
                        D2D1_CAP_STYLE_ROUND,
                        D2D1_LINE_JOIN_MITER,
                        10.0f,
                        D2D1_DASH_STYLE_DASH_DOT,//D2D1_DASH_STYLE_CUSTOM,
                        0.0f),
                0,//dashes,
                0,//ARRAYSIZE(dashes),
                &m_strokeStyle
                );
}
```

Into OnDraw2d(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) :

```
    pRenderTarget->DrawLine(CPoint(rectGraph.left,rect.bottom), CPoint(rectGraph.right,rect.bottom), m_pBlackBrush, 1.0, m_strokeStyle);
```

But the same line without StrokeStyle is working fine :

```
    pRenderTarget->DrawLine(CPoint(rectGraph.left,rect.bottom), CPoint(rectGraph.right,rect.bottom), m_pBlackBrush, 1.0, NULL);
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: You should have some error code returned, possibly that stroke style and render targets belong to different factories.

Comment: I think I found the explaination. Apparently, since VS2010, the D2DFactory is created "globally" when I call EnableD2DSupport();

So instead of creating another D2D1CreateFactory(), I put this code :

    static AFX_GLOBAL_DATA globals;

and on my constructor :
    m_pD2DFactory = globals.GetDirect2dFactory();

And it works. Not sure why the second factory is not allowed and how it's supposed to work with the "new way".

Comment: It is allowed. Not allowed is mixing objects from different factories.

Comment: That's probably what happen : D2D methods are probably using the global factory in theirs implémentations. Like the DrawLine() ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a mystery why MS had to make it so hard. As of December 2020, the following worked for me in VS2019: declare a member variable in CView-derived class

```
_AFX_D2D_STATE* m_pD2DState = nullptr;
```

In constructor, initialize it

```
EnableD2DSupport();
m_pD2DState = AfxGetD2DState();
```

At last - get factory and use it to create stroke style

```
ID2D1Factory *pFactory = m_pD2DState->GetDirect2dFactory();
pFactory->CreateStrokeStyle(...);
```